# Reference homebrew boost lib without the version number

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew, setuptools, setup.py

I have boost installed using homebrew.

In my `setup.py` file I reference a boost library this way:

```
BOOST_LIBDIR = '/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0/lib
Extension(...., library_dirs = `BOOST_LIBDIR`, ...)
```

Is there some way I can use this library without referencing version 1.60.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/usr/local/opt/boost/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.